# Using openldap to connect to Active Directory SSL by trusting primary domain controller's CA cert

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

A lot has been written on this subject, but not quite my problem. The problem is that whatever I do, I can't get openldap tools (or PHP, which uses openldap), to accept a certificate signed by the primary domain controller's CA. But, it *is* valid, as openssl shows.

In a Windows network, all domain joined PCs have the CA cert of the domain controller as trusted. I mimicked that in Ubuntu:

```
cp -v /tmp/PDC02CA.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
update-ca-certificates
```

OpenSSL approves this (and it doesn't like it otherwise):

```
# openssl verify -verify_hostname PDC01.city.cmpny.local /tmp/PDC01.city.cmpny.local.crt
/tmp/PDC01.city.cmpny.local.crt: OK
```

But `ldapsearch` just will not approve it:

```
$ ldapsearch  -d1 -H ldaps://ldap.city.cmpny.local:3269/
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://ldap.city.cmpny.local:3269/)
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://ldap.city.cmpny.local:3269/??base)
ldap_pvt_sasl_getmech
ldap_search
put_filter: "(objectclass=*)"
put_filter: simple
put_simple_filter: "objectclass=*"
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP ldap.city.cmpny.local:3269
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 10.220.10.10:3269
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect success
TLS: peer cert untrusted or revoked (0x102)
TLS: can't connect: (unknown error code).
ldap_msgfree
ldap_err2string
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
        additional info: (unknown error code)
```

I tried all the things you can find on-line like setting `LDAPTLS_CACERT=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`, editing `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` with `TLS_CACERT`, etc. Only setting `TLS_REQCERT never` works, but of course I don't want that.

When I set `TLS_CACERTDIR`, `ldapsearch` says: "TLS: warning: cacertdir not implemented for gnutls"

*Some* validation works. If I do `ldapsearch  -d1 -H ldaps://www.google.com:443/`, it's fine (aside from the fact that it's not LDAP).

I suspect it's a difference in how OpenSSL and GnuTLS validate, but from what I can find, GnuTLS noways also looks at `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`. And `strace` proves it:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=201737, ...}) = 0
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
mmap(NULL, 204800, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe84e7e3000
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=201737, ...}) = 0
read(4, "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIH"..., 200704) = 200704
read(4, "swGQYDVQQDExJBbG1lcmUtVklD\nUERDM"..., 4096) = 1033
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)
```

It shows it's 201737 bytes, and reads it in two passes, first yielding 200704 bytes, then 1033 bytes.

Setting `LDAPTLS_CACERT=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/PDC02CA.crt`, `strace` shows it reads that instead. Still doesn't work.

Edit: I did just notice the certificate has an empty subject, so no `CN` (common name). It only has an `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name`. Hmm, that could be it. Takes some work to test.